# dpkg-genchanges: error: cannot read dsc

Tags: deb, packaging, debian, debuild

I want to bump the version of `libqca-qt5-2` package to 2.2.0.

```
# get sources
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/qca.git
git archive HEAD --prefix=qca-qt5-2.2.0/ -o qca-qt5-2.2.0.tar.xz

mkdir ../deb-qca
cd ../deb-qca

# make a new release
apt-get source libqca-qt5-2
cp ../qca/qca-qt5-2.2.0.tar.xz .
cd qca-qt5-2.1.1/
uupdate -v 2.2.0 ../qca-qt5-2.2.0.tar.xz
cd ../qca-qt5-2.2.0
rm debian/patches/fix_build_without_sslv3.diff
sed -i -e '/fix_build_without_sslv3.diff/d' debian/patches/series
while dquilt push; do dquilt refresh; done
dch

# build
debuild -eDEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="parallel=4" -b -uc -us
```

(also there is some patching in `qca_plugin.h` and `qca_plugin.c`: need to move `class QCA_EXPORT PluginInstance` into the header)

The error when packaging is the following:

```
...
  _ZNK3QCA6Cipher2okEv@Base 2.0.2
+ _ZNK3QCA6Cipher3tagEv@Base 2.2.0-0ubuntu1
  _ZNK3QCA6Cipher4modeEv@Base 2.0.2
  _ZNK3QCA6Cipher4typeEv@Base 2.0.2
  _ZNK3QCA6Cipher7paddingEv@Base 2.0.2
dh_shlibdeps  
set -e; \
if [ -n "`ls debian/*.substvars 2>/dev/null`" ]; then \
    echo "Generating strict local shlibs on packages: libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqca-qt5-2"; \
    sed -i '/^shlibs:[^=]\+=/{ s/\(^shlibs:[^=]\+=[[:space:]]*\|,[[:space:]]*\)\(libqca-qt5-2-plugins\|libqca-qt5-2\|_\)\([[:space:]]*([[:space:]]*[><=]\+[^)]\+)\)\?/\1\2 (= 2.2.0-0ubuntu1)/g }' debian/*.substvars; \
    fi
Generating strict local shlibs on packages: libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqca-qt5-2
dh_installdeb  
dh_sameversiondep
dh_gencontrol  
dh_md5sums  
dh_builddeb -u-Zxz  
dpkg-deb: building package 'qca-qt5-2-utils' in '../qca-qt5-2-utils_2.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package 'libqca-qt5-2-plugins' in '../libqca-qt5-2-plugins_2.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package 'libqca-qt5-2-dbg' in '../libqca-qt5-2-dbg_2.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package 'libqca-qt5-2' in '../libqca-qt5-2_2.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb'.
dpkg-deb: building package 'libqca-qt5-2-dev' in '../libqca-qt5-2-dev_2.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb'.
=== Start list-missing
-./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qca-qt5/crypto/libqca-gcrypt.so
=== End list-missing
dpkg-genchanges > ../.pkg-kde-lintian.changes
dpkg-genchanges: error: cannot read ../qca-qt5_2.2.0-0ubuntu1.dsc: No such file or directory
/usr/share/pkg-kde-tools/qt-kde-team/3/lintian.mk:20: recipe for target 'lintian' failed
make[1]: *** [lintian] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/data/hd2/cryptography/qca-deb/qca-qt5-2.2.0'
/usr/share/pkg-kde-tools/qt-kde-team/3/dhmk.mk:112: recipe for target 'debian/dhmk_binary' failed
make: *** [debian/dhmk_binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -b failed
```

Packages are fine and working.

Why `qca-qt5_2.2.0-0ubuntu1.dsc: No such file or directory`?

We specified a build without signing... And the doc https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/update.en.html#newupstream says nothing about `dsc`.

Comment: why changes had wrong name: `pkg-kde-lintian.changes`.  may be you had a package naming conflict somewhere between: source archive, parent folder  & debian changelog.